# Encoding issue: An NSString into a key of an NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, character-encoding, utf-16

So I'm taking a data file and encoding it into a string:

```
                ///////////////////////////////
                // Get the string

                NSString* dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                             encoding:encoding];

                NSLog(@"dataString = %@",dataString);
```

The file was a list of French words and they `NSLog` fine, showing appropriate accents (just one example):

```
abandonnèrent
```

Now, in the very next part of the code I take this `NSString` of the file contents and convert it to a dictionary where the words are the keys and the objects are two additional dictionaries:

```
               ///////////////////////////////
               // Now parse the file (string)

                NSMutableDictionary *mutableWordlist = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

                int i = 0;
                for (NSString *line in [dataString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]) {
                    NSArray *words = [line componentsSeparatedByString:@"\t"];

                    NSNumber *count = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(i+1)];

                    NSArray *keyArray;
                    NSArray *objectArray;


                    if ([words count] < 2) { // No native word
                        keyArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"frequency",  nil];
                        objectArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:count,  nil];

                    }
                    else {
                        keyArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"frequency", @"native", nil];
                        objectArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:count, [words[1] lowercaseString], nil];

                    }

                    NSDictionary *detailsDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:objectArray forKeys:keyArray];

                    [mutableWordlist setObject:detailsDict forKey:[words[0] lowercaseString]];

                    i++;
                }


                self.wordlist = mutableWordlist;

                NSLog(@"self.wordlist = %@", self.wordlist);
```

But here the keys have encoding issues and log as so if they have an accent:

```
"abandonn\U00e8rent
" =     {
        frequency = 24220;
    };
```

What is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing (wrong) is happening.

When you `NSLog` an `NSString` it is being output as Unicode text. However when you `NSLog` the `NSDictionary` they keys are being output with unicode escape sequences, `\U00e8` is the escape code you can use in a string if you cannot type an `è` - say because your source file is in ASCII.

So the difference is only in how the string is being printed, the string is not different.

HTH