# Text encoding issue for NSDictionary in iOS

Tags: objective-c, character-encoding, special-characters, nsmutabledictionary, flurry

In my iOS app , I have Flurry SDK for analytics. Now everything is working correctly except the special symbols are not showing correctly in Flurry. `tags` is `NSMutableArray` which stores the tag for my data. It can contain alphabets , special symbols , numbers etc. Here is my code

```
-(void)addTestDetails
{
    NSArray *array = @[@":);&;@-(-@;""-~£~¥>=#+{!|!_'",@"'%%+|*",@"TestTag",@"123:;?&",@">|€~€",@":-(/$:&"];
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [params setObject:array forKey:@"Tags"];
    [params setObject:@"test" forKey:@"Title"];
    NSLog(@"params: %@",params);
}
```

When I debug , its showing me correct symbols without any encoding issue. Please have a look at below screenshots

[image]

[image]

But its shows as unicode as when I use NSLog below

```
params: {
Tags =     (
    ":);&;@-(-@;-~\U00a3~\U00a5>=#+{!|!_'",
    "'%%+|*",
    TestTag,
    "123:;?&",
    ">|\U20ac~\U20ac",
    ":-(/$:&"
);
Title = test;
}
```

I read some questions on stackoverflow regarding [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21469627/encoding-issue-an-nsstring-into-a-key-of-an-nsdictionary) which says its default & nothing wrong in it. If its correct , why its showing the same output in Flurry events as well when I download the data from Flurry server ? It should show me the correct symbols in there , right ? Correct me if I am wrong.

I tried using

`[params setObject:[array componentsJoinedByString:@","] forKey:@"Tags"];`

but still same issue.
Is there any other way I can fix this issue ?

Can anybody help me with this issue ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it'll help

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithCString:contentString encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```